# Dasherize attributes names with JSONAPI-RB serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, json-api, jsonapi-rb

I am migrating from AMS to jsonapi-rb for my JSON-API serializer.

My question is about attributes names in the context of serializing.
Is there a way to automatically replace underscore (`some_attribute`) in attributes name to dash (`some-attribute`), so that the attributes names appear as dasherized in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and ended up finding some documentation in the [source code](https://github.com/jsonapi-rb/jsonapi-serializable/blob/02e9e4df43a94528a56ffc4d71a630e81e9841f2/lib/jsonapi/serializable/resource/key_format.rb#L4)

> Extension for handling automatic key formatting of
> attributes/relationships.
>
> @example
> class SerializableUser < JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource
> extend JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource::KeyFormat
> key_format ->(key) { key.camelize }.
>
> attribute :user_name.
> has_many :close_friends
> end
> => will modify the serialized keys to `UserName` and `CloseFriends`.

I used `dasherize` to achieve the translation from `some_attribute` to `some-attribute`

Example:

```
class SerializableUser < JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource
  extend JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource::KeyFormat
  key_format -> (key) { key.to_s.dasherize }
end
```